# SQL Server 2014 if exists with multiple begin and end

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this line of codes:

```
if exists(select a.id, a.user_id 
          from AEmployeeLogs a
          inner join AUsers b on b.id = a.user_id
          where b.username = @username 
            and b.password = @password
            and convert(date, a.date_in) = convert(date, dateadd(HOUR, 15, getdate())))
    select 'Exist' as result;
else
begin
    select 
        a.id, username, firstname, lastname, user_image, UserType, title,
        'user_type_title', is_cashier, 
        case
           when @num is null then 1
           else @num + 1
        end 'number'
    from 
        dbo.AUsers a
    inner join 
        ALookUp b on b.id = a.UserType
    left join
        AEmployeeLogs c on c.user_id = a.id
    where 
        a.username = @username and a.password = @password

end

    declare @id int;
    select @id = a.id
    from dbo.AUsers a
    INNER JOIN ALookUp b
    on b.id = a.UserType            
    where username = @username and password = @password

begin

        INSERT INTO AEmployeeLogs (date_in,[user_id],note,isactive)
        select dateadd(HOUR, 15, getdate()), @id, '',0
        where @id is not null

end
```

The `If Exists` function works properly, but when I looked at the table `AEmployeeLogs`, it still inserts even though the is exists what is the proper way of writing my else statement when i have multiple begin and end functions in my query

NOTE: The first begin and end works it didn't select but the 2nd one works need help

Comment: Your Insert Into AEmployeeLogs will always execute, it has left the scope of your if/else block. The first End is where the scope is finished. It sounds like you may just need to get rid of the End right before you declare @id and then the following Begin.

Comment: so does this query work if i have them in one begin and end @MikeR

Comment: Yes the query should work if your else statement has just one set of Begin & End.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like already stated in the comments, the scope of the `else` has already ended after the first `end`.

Like following, it should work as expected:

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT a.id,
            a.user_id
        FROM AEmployeeLogs a
        INNER JOIN AUsers b ON b.id = a.user_id
        WHERE b.username = @username
            AND b.password = @password
            AND CONVERT(DATE, a.date_in) = CONVERT(DATE, dateadd(HOUR, 15, getdate()))
        )
    SELECT 'Exist' AS result;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT a.id, username, firstname, lastname, user_image, UserType, title, 'user_type_title', is_cashier, 
            CASE 
                WHEN @num IS NULL
                    THEN 1
                ELSE @num + 1
                END 'number'
        FROM dbo.AUsers a
        INNER JOIN ALookUp b ON b.id = a.UserType
        LEFT JOIN AEmployeeLogs c ON c.user_id = a.id
        WHERE a.username = @username
            AND a.password = @password

        DECLARE @id INT;

        SELECT @id = a.id
        FROM dbo.AUsers a
        INNER JOIN ALookUp b ON b.id = a.UserType
        WHERE username = @username
            AND password = @password

        INSERT INTO AEmployeeLogs (
            date_in,
            [user_id],
            note,
            isactive
            )
        SELECT dateadd(HOUR, 15, getdate()),
            @id,
            '',
            0
        WHERE @id IS NOT NULL
    END
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help